# ec2 amazon linux 413 Request Entity Too Large Error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-linux

Getting "413 Request Entity Too Large" in amazon linux installed on ec2 instance on uploading 5 MB or large file. Want to transfer around 100 MB data but not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image: issue]

I tried adding "client_max_body_size 100" inside nginx.conf file like this.

[image]

And restarted nginx multiple times using "sudo service reload nginx", "sudo systemctl reload nginx" commands, but still getting this issue again and again.

I am very new to nginx so not sure if I am doing anything wrong or not. Can anyone please guide through steps to solve this issue? That will be really helpful!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by replacing 100 with 100M as value of client_max_body_size 100M.

and restart nginx using "systemctl restart nginx".